# Problem with Pnet model when intergrate to ios app

Tags: ios, artificial-intelligence

My Xcode is 10.1 when i am using pnet model which is converted to integrated to ios app and i saw error

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'of:', expected 'rawValue:')

with line below in pnet.swift. How can I resolve this issue:

```
convenience init() {
        try! self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle)
 }
```

Comment: Can u provide more details? how did you converted the model to Swift? or link to reference model?

Comment: Yes i try other model and saw the same error. Maybe error come from config project of Xcode without model. I have got other project from internet and build with this model it fine. do u have solution for this ? below is link model:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qoh10hhTRbSfjqFEp7Pot-EainudHhoh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share your xcode project? on google drive or github?

Comment: this is project develop by my company it is private project. i can't

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R1NpEy5a0m8ddnUDdmYyX_vcFzbjSecg/view?usp=sharing . here is screenshot erorr

Comment: which swift version and xcode version are you using?

Comment: Swift version is 4 and Xcode version is 10.1. my project  can't not run with xcode 10.2 just only 10.1 working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    try pnet(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "your path here"))
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Try it like this or write your own child class with initializers

```
class pnet2: pnet {

convenience init() {
    try! self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle)
}

convenience init(hah: Bool = true) {
    try! self.init(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
}
```

}

Comment: Class pnet is created automatic by xcode when add file pnet.mlmodel i can't change this. i tried created file pnet2.swift extend pnet class like you show and got error "Cannot convert value of type 'pnet2' to expected argument type 'Int'"

Comment: Yes the class is autogenerated, you do not need to change it... that is why i suggested that you should subclass with your own..where are you using this pnet2 class again?

Comment: the problem seems to be in the usage not the class itself.. how are you trying to use these classes?

Comment: i just only add file pnet.mlmodel to myproject and build and i don't used autogenerated class with any class in project  and then got this broblem. i can't build project

Comment: error come from xcode or myproject maybe it is config part of Xcode. but i did not know

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R1NpEy5a0m8ddnUDdmYyX_vcFzbjSecg/view?usp=sharing here is screen shot